# mod_rewrite with directory name matching pattern

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been dealing for hours with a mod_rewrite problem.
I am working with a localhost under Windows. Apache 2.4 with XAMPP

I am trying to do a RewriteRule from my local htaccess with no success. This is the rule:

```
RewriteRule Event/(.*)$ event/this-event.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

What I need to rewrite is: Event/4027 to event/this-event?id=4027

The thing is that I have a directory called event so the Event from the pattern is getting confused with the event directory. If I change Event from the pattern to any other word it works fine.

```
RewriteRule AnyWord/(.*)$ event/this-event.php?id=$1 [L,R=301] # This works!
```

htaccess file is located in the DOCUMENT_ROOT folder and the content is just:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase / 

# and the RewriteRule
```

I have tried every tip, trick, advice I have found. I have tried several variations of the rule, using ^Event or (*.)/Event, etc. Also tried using RewriteCond to check if exists file inside directory or if exists directory.
I have disabled the mod_speling module just in case the uppercase was disturbing. Also have tried using Options -Multiviews.

I couldn't get none of these to work. If someone can give me an advice I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that the  target path /event/this-event.php matches the pattern Event/(.*)$ and rewrites it to itself.

You need to exclude the target path from rewrite to get this rule to work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/event/this-event\.php$
RewriteRule ^Event/(.+)$ event/this-event.php?id=$1 [NC,L,R]
```

The rewriteCond is important here ,it checks if the request is /event/this-event.php ,skip the rule.

Remove the R Flag from last rule  if you want the url not to change in browser.

Comment: Hi Starkeen. Thanks. I have tried and what I get is the following rewritten URL: **http://localhost/project/event/this-event.php?id=this-event.php**. Curiously is sending this-event.php as a parameter.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Done. Still getting the same parameter.

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: localhost/project/event/this-event.php?id=SomeID

Comment: Your question is confusing me, where is the htaccess located? is project a folder?

Comment: I have the following local directory structure:
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\event.

project is a folder. htaccess is located in htdocs.

Comment: Ok. It worked now but only if I take away the ^ before Event in the RewriteRule. The thing now is that I have images in the folder localhost/project/img/event which are not showing.

Comment: That is because the header uri has changed from / to /event/ ,if you view the source code of your page, you will see that images are trying to load as <img src="/event/foo.jpg">, to solve this, simply add **<base href="/">** inbetween <head>and </head> this sets the base to /

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule event/(.*)$ event/this-event.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and the url works for both

```
http://localhost/project/Event/500
http://localhost/project/event/500
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting an Internal Server Error with this rule.